# SQL / PHP - only display the first value of my database

Tags: php, sql, oracle

All is in the title. why I only get the first line of my table and not all the fields.

Function :

```
class Services_Label extends Services_Abstract
{
    public function getlibelle()
    {
        $sRequest = 'SELECT NAME FROM menu WHERE id_application = 2';
        $this->executeQueries($sRequest);
        $aResult = $this->getOneResult();
        $this->freeStatement();
        return $aResult;
     }
 }
```

function application :

```
$oMessage = new Services_Label();

$toto = $oMessage->getlibelle();

var_dump($toto);
```

answer :

```
string(15) "Prise en charge"
```

table : [image]

Comment: You only select the `NAME` column in your query! If you want other columns you have to add them to the list or use `SELECT *` to get all of them

Comment: How does the function 'getOneResult()' look like? Also column names would make the table nicer.

Comment: Please consider rephrase your question. In the title you are asking to display only one row. Then in the question you are saying you want to get all the fields (=columns). But I think what you really want is to get all rows from the field 'name'. Please correct me, if I am mistaken.

Comment: you right i want to get all rows from the field name, but its ok i found the answer !

Comment: Glad to hear, but please still consider editing the question and also provide the solution or mark at least the answer that got you on the right track. Point is that it should be possible for other people to get a good answer out of this.

Answer (score 1):

Going by the name of the `getOneResult()`, your resultset is probably being limited to one result.

Can you post the whole function to confirm?

Comment: Using `id_application = 2` I would sort of expect only one row to be returned, but I admit its a bit of an assumption

Comment: @RiggsFolly im assuming the last column containing 2 is the id_application column. So all rows should be returned. If thats the case then the getOneResult() function may be doing some additional filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea from your question what your table columns are called, but if you want all of the columns use `SELECT *`

```
class Services_Label extends Services_Abstract
{
    public function getlibelle()
    {
        $sRequest = 'SELECT * FROM menu WHERE id_application = 2';
        $this->executeQueries($sRequest);
        $aResult = $this->getOneResult();
        $this->freeStatement();
        return $aResult;
     }
 }
```

It is most often better to actually name only the columns you actually want returned so you would do that like this

```
class Services_Label extends Services_Abstract
{
    public function getlibelle()
    {
        $sRequest = 'SELECT NAME,COL2,COL3 FROM menu WHERE id_application = 2';
        $this->executeQueries($sRequest);
        $aResult = $this->getOneResult();
        $this->freeStatement();
        return $aResult;
     }
 }
```

Comment: No i want to display all the name col, no other

Answer (score 0):

this is the function getoneresult()

```
 public function getOneResult()
{
    $row = $this->getNextRow(OCI_BOTH | OCI_RETURN_NULLS);

    if (is_array($row)) {
        return $row[0];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: When i change the $row[0] in $row[3] my identification form doesnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect the rows using a while loop. So change your function 'getOneResult' to something like this.

```
public function getResults()
{
    $array = array();
    while ($row = $this->getNextRow(OCI_BOTH | OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
        $array[] = $row;
    } 
    return $array;
}
```